# Error: attribute android:hintTextColor not found

Tags: android, edittext

Tengo este código en el activity_main.xml de *Android Studio*.

Me muestra el siguiente error:

> ERROR:C:\Users\Luciana\AndroidStudioProjects\Intentocalculadora\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml:34: AAPT: error: attribute android:hintTextColor not found.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/numero_1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/txt_numero1"
    android:hintTextColor="#757575"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:minHeight="48dp"
    tools:ignore="TextContrastCheck" />            /*  linea 34*/


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/numero_2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/txt_numero2"
    android:hintTextColor="#757575"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:minHeight="48dp"
    tools:ignore="TextContrastCheck" />       /* linea 46*/
```

Comment: Has intentado usar `textColorHint` en lugar de `hintTextColor`?

Comment: Hola John es textColorHint en lugar de hintTextColor, agregue una respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Me parece que te estas confundiendo...

**Es `textColorHint` en lugar de `hintTextColor`.**

[`textColorHint` es un atributo de `TextInputLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/textfield/TextInputLayout#attr_TextInputLayout_hintTextColor), pero no de `EditText`.

Deberías agregar el `EditText` dentro de un `TextInputLayout` y asignar `textColorHint` a tu `TextInputLayout` , ejemplo:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:textColorHint="#757575"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/numero_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/txt_numero1"
        android:hintTextColor="#757575"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        tools:ignore="TextContrastCheck" /> 
 </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

Prueba a poner el siguiente código:

```
android:textColorHint="#757575"
```